# Is there a function that will take an existing series of values in oracle SQL for Apex and will make a trendline based on those values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, trendline

I would like to create a trendline based on the values returned from a query. The logic needs to be applicable for other cases of placing a trendlines on series in Oracle PLSQL with Apex.

My series has X values that are dates and Y values that are time values. Here is my query that outputs my dates and Y values:

```
Select  
                null link,
                (START_DATE) label, 

                Round(Avg(Run_TIME),3) "Average Length"

from 
            (Select job_id,
                    (Case :P4_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                    END) "START_DATE",  
                    1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME) "RUN_TIME"
            from apps.NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V@util.world

            WHERE

        (:P4_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Tiny' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 1
        OR

        :P4_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Small' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 1 AND 
                        (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 5
        OR

        :P4_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Medium' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 5 AND 
                        (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 20
        OR
        :P4_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Large' AND ((1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 20)
        OR
        :P4_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER NOT IN('Small','Medium','Large','Tiny') AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 0)

        AND
        (INFA_TYPE_CODE = 'WORKFLOW')
        AND
        OBJECT_NAME = :P4_WORKFLOWNAMES
        AND
        (
        :P4_Data_Volume_Chooser = 'Small' AND SUCCESS_SOURCE_ROWS < 100
        OR
        :P4_Data_Volume_Chooser = 'Medium' AND SUCCESS_SOURCE_ROWS > 99 AND SUCCESS_SOURCE_ROWS < 10000
        OR
        :P4_Data_Volume_Chooser = 'Large' AND SUCCESS_SOURCE_ROWS > 9999
        OR
        :P4_Data_Volume_Chooser NOT IN ('Small','Medium','Large')
        )
          )

        WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN  
                    (Case :P4_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(to_date(:P4_BEGIN_DATES, 'MM-DD-YY'))
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(to_date(:P4_BEGIN_DATES, 'MM-DD-YY'), 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(to_date(:P4_BEGIN_DATES, 'MM-DD-YY'), 'MM') END) 

                AND
                    (Case :P4_DATE_CHOOSER
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(to_date(:P4_END_DATE, 'MM-DD-YY'))
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(to_date(:P4_END_DATE, 'MM-DD-YY'), 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(to_date(:P4_END_DATE, 'MM-DD-YY'), 'MM') END)

 group by START_DATE 
 order by START_DATE
        ;
```

Ideally, I'd be able to use my existing query as the source for a new subquery.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking.  If you are creating a scatter plot chart in APEX based on that, you should be able to add a trendline to that plot.  If that's what you're doing, however, I'd expect to see a lot more information about the chart in your question and less about the underlying query (i.e. that you're using APEX 4.2 with a Flash scatter plot, etc.).  Are you trying to generate the trendline in the SQL query itself rather than as part of the presentation?  What sort of trend line do you want (linear least squares?  second degree polynomial?)

Comment: If you're trying to generate the trendline in SQL, you probably want to look at the various linear regression functions http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions132.htm in SQL.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a linear-least sqaure within the sql. I need it to generate all the points of the trendline as if it were another series.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to look at the linear regression functions I linked to.